# I am trying to bind my FormView to show the Form in djangocms but i am not able to

Tags: django-cms, formview

I am trying to bind my `FormView` to show the `Form` in djangocms but I am not able to,
my model is:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView, CMSPlugin):
    template = '/ContactForm/ContactForm.html'
    form_class = contact_form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success-page')

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        assert request.is_ajax()
        request_data = json.loads(request.body)
        form = self.form_class(data=request_data[self.form_class.scope_prefix])
        if form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({'success_url': force_text(self.success_url)})
        else:
            response_data = {form.form_name: form.errors}
            return JsonResponse(response_data, status=422)
```

cms_plugins.py:

```
class ContactFormPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ContactForm.ContactFormView
    render_template = '/ContactForm/ContactForm.html'
    name = 'Contact Form'
    allow_children = False

plugin_pool.register_plugin(ContactFormPlugin)
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving.  "I am not able to" isn't enough information.

Comment: the Form is not showing up on the view, this is my problem, there is no debug / runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you've got there, I'm not sure you've given your plugin a proper model but a view!? And the form class isn't a form class, `form_class = contact_form` but what is `contact_form`? You need it to be the class of your form e.g.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your email', max_length=100)


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template = '/ContactForm/ContactForm.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success-page')
```

And if you've got a form you want your plugin to render, you need to tell it what to do...

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

class ContactFormPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CMSPlugin
    render_template = '/ContactForm/ContactForm.html'
    name = 'Contact Form'
    allow_children = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ContactFormPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        context['form'] = ContactForm()
        return context
```

However you're working with a CMS plugin, so you don't define a `View` at all for a plugin. I think you could make this do what you're trying to do but the view doesn't want to inherit `CMSPlugin` because you just want a view to receive data from the plugin.

If you need to define views then you're building an app which in CMS requires an `Apphook`, not a plugin. (Technically you could post to a URL without an Apphook, but depends how much CMS integration you want)

There is a great example that starts with a plugin posting to a view then progresses into the app integration which is possible here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/plugins.html